# Issue building a char from sting and variables

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to build a string or character to send to a function.

error:

```
In member function 'void RTSSHOW::RTS_Init()':
Marlin/src/lcd/e3v2/creality/LCD_RTS.cpp:383:37: warning: '%f' directive writing between 3 and 317 bytes into a region of size 0 [-Wformat-overflow=]
  383 |         sprintf_P((char*)mstr, PSTR("%s %f"), mstr, z_values[x][y] * 1000);
```

Short code summary:

```
auto mstr = (char*)""; // here is the string I'm trying to build

sprintf_P((char*)mstr, PSTR("%s %f"), mstr, z_values[x][y] * 1000);

sprintf_P((char*)mstr, PSTR("%s %s"), mstr, "\n");

RTS_SndData((char*)mstr, AUTO_BED_LEVEL_MESH_VP);
```

here is my code pastebin: https://pastebin.com/xrk2GJsh

I'm not fluent in C++ and building a string is not the same as in PHP which I am used to.

I've tried various string and char declarations, but cannot seem to get it.

Comment: `(char*)""` __Do not do this__. If you don't cast, you'll get an error message, I assume thats why you casted here but that just hides the underlying problem.

Comment: What is your code supposed to do?

Comment: TLDR: In C++, generally use std::string rather than C style strings and C library functions, as you are doing in your code.

Comment: *I'm not fluent in C++ and building a string is not the same as in PHP which I am used to.* -- [std::string](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string)

Comment: You should look into `std::ostringstream` for this

Comment: Or `std::format()`

Comment: You need to learn about memory allocation. `auto mstr = (char*)"";` does not allocate working memory like you think. "" is constant for a reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some guess work here, but I would try something like this

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

std::ostringstream mstr;
mstr << z_values[x][y] * 1000 << '\n';
RTS_SndData(mstr.str().c_str(), AUTO_BED_LEVEL_MESH_VP);
```

If that's not quite the correct string, no doubt you can tinker with the code.

Somewhat less flexible, but maybe less heavy is this

```
#include <string>

std::string mstr = std::to_string(z_values[x][y] * 1000) + "\n";
RTS_SndData(mstr.c_str(), AUTO_BED_LEVEL_MESH_VP);
```

Comment: This allowed me to compile now without errors. I will test and see if it now outputs the string to my display.

Comment: This makes the .bin file too large and will not load up on my 3d printer running marlin.. Including this library takes it from 171k to 305k and I'm thinking the board cannot handle that large of bin. I need another solution.

Comment: @johncarlson21 I've posted another version, but really I have no idea how much extra code it might add to your .bin file.

Comment: This actually compiled and is just a bit more code, so I think this will work fine. I will let ya know if something comes up. Thank you.